# Define a block in a class to use elsewhere

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im trying to define a block type in a class so that I can then use it in other classes.

I've put this in the .h of a class that is used everywhere...

```
typedef void (^ProgressBlock)(float progress);
```

but I'd now like to use this block in other places.

I have a class that imports the correct .h file but the `ProgressBlock` is not available. Is there any way to define the block so I can use it in multiple classes?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem with the way you implement it. If you import the `.h` file, the block should be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a constants file (C and C++ Header file) define you block in there. Import that file where ever you want to use the block.

Comment: time restrictions - 8 minutes remaining.