# Block definition available throughout project without duplicate symbol error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, block

here is a block that I've defined, which compares 2 UIViews:

```
typedef NSComparisonResult(^UITagCompareBlock)(UIView*, UIView*);

UITagCompareBlock uiTagCompareBlock = ^NSComparisonResult(UIView* a, UIView* b){

  if (a.tag < b.tag) return NSOrderedAscending;
  else if (a.tag > b.tag) return NSOrderedDescending;
  else return NSOrderedSame;
};
```

I use this in the following way, to sort an array of UIViews:

```
self.arrayOfViews = [self.arrayOfViews sortedArrayUsingComparator: uiTagCompareBlock];
```

All works well, but if I try to spin this block and typedef definition into its own file, so I can use the same block throughout the project, I get duplicate symbol errors upon compiling. How can I have this available in the whole project?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250290/define-a-block-in-a-class-to-use-elsewhere/18250319#18250319

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you defined the block in a .h file, so that it is defined in every .m file
that imports this .h file?

You have to *declare* it in a .h file:

```
typedef NSComparisonResult(^UITagCompareBlock)(UIView*, UIView*);
extern UITagCompareBlock uiTagCompareBlock;
```

and *define* it in exactly one .m file:

```
UITagCompareBlock uiTagCompareBlock = ^NSComparisonResult(UIView* a, UIView* b){

  if (a.tag < b.tag) return NSOrderedAscending;
  else if (a.tag > b.tag) return NSOrderedDescending;
  else return NSOrderedSame;
};
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, looks good... the use of extern here was something I wasn't aware of.

Comment: And to make the most sense, you would declare it in the .h file for that .m file.